# Export all classes for npm library module

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm new to JS infrastructure, and I'm trying to understand `npm` modules.
I'm creating JavaScript `npm` module with several classes. Let's call it `Foo` and `Bar` for example, `Foo` class is located in `./src/foo.js` file and `Bar` class in `./src/bar.js`:

```js
// ./src/foo.js
export default class Foo {}
```

and

```js
// ./src/bar.js
export default class Bar {}
```

Also, I have `./src/index.js` where I want to export `Foo` and `Bar` to make it accessible from other modules:

```js
import Foo from './foo.js';
import Bar from './bar.js';
```

What I want, is to name my module `foobar` for example, and publish it to `npmjs`, then install it using `npm install --save foobar` from other module and import `Foo` and `Bar` from `foobar` module:

```js
import {Foo, Bar} from 'foobar';
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
```

What should I do with `index.js` file to export `Foo` and `Bar` globally (on module level) to be able importing it from other module?

Comment: you could write it like that `export { Foo, Bar }` and I think it will work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Federkun pointed out, you can use the following syntax:

```
import Foo from './foo.js'
import Bar from './bar.js'

export { Foo, Bar }
```

Using ECMAScript 6 [*Object Literal Property Value Shorthand*](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand), the above code is equivalent to the following:

```
import Foo from './foo.js'
import Bar from './bar.js'

export { Foo: Foo, Bar: Bar }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `index.js` you should export what you want to expose to the clients of your packages.

```
import Foo from './foo.js'
import Bar from './bar.js'

export { Foo, Bar }
```